# OpenVPN on Ubuntu: IP Forwarding not working

Tags: iptables, openvpn, ip-forwarding

I have successfully set up a VPN connection between a Windows 8 client and my Ubuntu server running OpenVPN.
However, I just cannot get IP forwarding to work.
I have adjusted all settings as desribed [here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect) but whenever I open a website in my browser I still have the same IP and traffic isn't routed over the server's IP.

I made sure that `net/ipv4/ip_forward=1` and that I restarted the server and the client after updates in the config.

Here's an extract of my server.conf:

```
proto udp
dev tun
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Extract of the client.ovpn:

```
client
dev tun
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

All certificate files are set correctly and I can connect to the VPN with my Windows client. Just the IP forwarding is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: just run your windows client "as administrator". It will very likely solve your problem. If not please provide more information about your network configuration: iptables rules, default gateway on your server

Comment: if openvpn is not run "as administrator" it can run and connect but it has not enough privileges to add new routes.. Anyway if you install a recent 64bits package ( 2.3+ if I remember well ) this issue should be solved.